# Tips on recreating an animated graph in html5, javascript, css

Tags: javascript, css, html, mobile, graph

I wish to recreate this animated, interactive graph

-> http://www.trefis.com/stock/axp/model/trefis?freeAccessToken=PROVIDER_28bfe6072583a2d1372e2786423e2e5a1c6307b8

in a mobile app I am creating using html5, javascript and css. Obviously I don't want to copy the graph  completely. Just some tips on where to start would be helpful as I am relatively new at programming in these languages (used to C, python). If there are any tutorials which would be relevant I'd appreciate any starting points on which to build.

Thanks,
K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like D3JS sounds like it would suit you.

http://d3js.org/

Here's something similar to what you are looking for specifically:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083